# Deciphering the purpose of a function in C with two for nested loops, one int input and an int return

Tags: c, math

A friend from another college came to me with this challenge. I was unable to help him, and became rather troubled as I can't understand the purpose of the function he was supposed to decipher. Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

I've tried visualising the data, but couldn't really take any meaningful conclusions out of the graph:
[image]
(blue is the return value of `mistery`, orange is the difference between the last and the current return. The scale is logarithmic for easier reading.)

```
int mistery(int n){
    int i, j, res=0;
    for(i = n / 2; i <= n; i++){
        for(j = 2; j <= n; j *= 2){
          res += n / 2;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

It seems like random code, but I've actually seen the worksheet where this appears. Any input is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct code? The outer loop has no interaction with anything inside so it can be replaced with a multiplication. Also `n / 2` is a constant in `res += n/2` and also can be moved out to a single multiplication. Those 2 facts suggest that there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: as this code currently stands, it just computes the value of n/2 * floor(log n) * floor (n/2), the logarithm is base 2.

Comment: @YakovDan, I don't think you get the formula exactly right (for example the outer `for` loop is neither `n/2` nor `floor(n/2)`), but yes, this is close enough and makes no sense to me either.

Comment: @SergGr I have double-checked. It is.

Comment: @SergGr, sure, The correct value is floor(n/2) +1.

Comment: In that case, it's just computes a function. nothing special about it.

Comment: That actually makes sense, as the loops do not interact with each other!

Comment: Indeed. it's basically n/2 plus n/2 plus n/2...., repeated k times. 
k seems to be (floor(n/2)+1) * floor (log n), but I suggest you double check this.

Comment: @SergGr, In my opinion, in an English sentence `n/2` is interpreted in its mathematical sense, not as an operator of the c programming language. Either way, when you write floor(n/2), you get the same numerical value in any interpretation you choose -  C, or math.

Answer (score 2):

The increment added to the result variable on each iteration of the inner loop depends only on function parameter *n*, which the function does not modify.  The result is therefore the product of the increment (`n/2`) with the total number of inner-loop iterations (supposing that does not overflow).

So how many loop iterations are there?  Consider first the outer loop.  If the lower bound of `i` were 0, then the inclusive upper bound of `n` would yield `n+1` iterations.  But we are skipping the first `n/2` iterations (0 ... `(n/2)-1`), so that's `n+1-(n/2)`.  All the divisions here are *integer* divisions, and with integer division it is true for all *m* that *m* = (*m*/2) + ((*m*+1)/2).  We can use that to rewrite the number of outer-loop iterations as `((n+1)/2) + 1`, or `(n+3)/2` (still using integer division).

Now consider the inner loop.  The index variable `j` starts at 2 and is doubled at every iteration until it exceeds `n`.  This yields a number of iterations equal to the floor of the base-2 logarithm of `n`.  The overall number of iterations is therefore

```
(n+3)/2 * floor(log2(n))
```

(supposing that we can assume an exact result when `n` is a power of 2).  The combined result, then, is

```
((n+3)/2) * (n/2) * floor(log2(n))
```

where the divisions are still integer divisions, and are performed before the multiplications.  This explains why the function's derivative spikes at power-of-2 arguments: the number of outer-loop iterations increases by one at each of those points.

We haven't any context from which to guess the purpose of the function, and I don't recognize it as a well-known function, but we can talk a bit about its properties.  For example,

- it grows asymptotically faster than *n*<sup>2</sup>, and asymptotically slower than *n*<sup>3</sup>.  In fact,
- it has a form reminiscent of those that tend to appear in computational asmyptotic bounds, so perhaps it is an estimate or bound for the memory or time that some computation will require.  Also,
- it is strictly increasing for *n* > 0.  That might not be immediately clear because of the involvement of integer division, but note that *n* and *n* + 3 have opposite parity, so whenever *n* increases by one, exactly one of *n*/2 and (*n*+3)/2 increases by one, while the other does not change (and the logarithmic term is non-decreasing).
- as already discussed, it has sudden jumps at powers of 2.  This can be viewed in terms of the number of iterations of the outer loop, or, alternatively, in terms of the involvement of the `floor()` function in the single-equation form.
- The polynomial part of the function is related to the equation for the sum of the integers from 1 to *n*.
- The logarithmic part of the function is related to the number of significant bits in the binary representation of *n*.